# PHP or JS? WooCommerce split/format decimal places into two rows

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce, decimalformat

I need to do a customization of *WooCommerce* product price display.
I need to format view to show decimal places smaller and above currency sign

[image]

Do I really need to edit core files? Has anyone had similar issue?

Comment: I tried this way, but it doesn't work - http://jsfiddle.net/vw8Ys/

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea (just tested myself). When you're inside your override templates and you can get `$product->get_price_html` how about running a regular expression to separate the floating point number. Then, explode that number into an array using the . delimiter.

say you're in `woocommerce/single-product/price.php` (copied into theme from plugin of course)

```
preg_match('!\d+(?:\.\d+)?!', $product->get_price_html(), $matches);
$price_parts = explode('.', $matches[0]);
print_r($price_parts); // for example outputs array('45', '00');
```

Better yet you can just get the raw price and forget the regular expression. Then get the currency separately.

```
$price_parts    = explode('.', $product->price);
$currency       = get_option('woocommerce_currency');
$currency_symbol= get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();

$price_html     = '<span class="price-big-number">'.$price_parts[0].'</span>';
$price_html     .='<span class="price-small-number">'.$price_parts[1].'</span>';
$price_html     .='<span class="price-currency">'.$currency.'</span>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely don't need to edit core files. 
Use filter

> [formatted_woocommerce_price](http://hookr.io/filters/formatted_woocommerce_price/)

to apply your changes on all pages where showed product price (including 'shop', 'single-product', 'cart', 'checkout').

E.g.

```
function my_custom_price_format( $formatted_price, $price, $decimals, $decimal_separator, $thousand_separator ) {
    $decimal_part = substr(strrchr($price, $decimal_separator), 1);
    return '<span class="int-part">' . floor( $price ) . '</span>' . '<sup class="decimal-part">' . $decimal_part . '</sup>';
}
add_filter( 'formatted_woocommerce_price', 'my_custom_price_format', 20, 5 );
```